# I have a problem angular service vs asp.net mvc controller do not connect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

Trying to put, method with two parametres, object in body and bool in url. 
but there is no connection between the service and controller. 
controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("putQuestionDifficulty/{id}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Question))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutQuestionDifficulty([FromBody] Question question, [FromUri] bool id)
    {
        var myquestion = db.Questions.Find(question);
        if (id)
        {
            myquestion.Difficulty++;
        }
        else myquestion.Difficulty--;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(question);
    }
```

service :

```
    putQuestionDifficulty(question: Question, id: boolean){
    return this.http.put<Question>(`${this.baseUrl}/putQuestionDifficulty/${id}`,question);
   }
```

Comment: Please find [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-put-request) `An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods.`

Comment: P.S. this appears to be a Web API controller, not an MVC controller. Check that you've got your terminology right and you understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your service and `subscribe` it to read the data

Call you `putQuestionDifficulty` method with specific prams

Try something like this in your component

```
this.putQuestionDifficulty(question, id).subscribe((res) => {
   console.log(res);
 });
```

Hope this will help you - Happy coding :)